# Reverse Linked List recursively, why it is wrong

Tags: recursion

Problem: Reverse a singly linked list recursively.

I know how to solve this problem, but one of my recursive methods is wrong, I can not figure out what's wrong with this code. Could anyone figure out that? Thanks a lot!

Test case: 
Input:
[1,2,3]
Output:
[3,1]
Expected:
[3,2,1]

```
public class Solution {
    // recursive
    ListNode last = null;
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        if (head == null)   return null;
        helper(head);
        return last;
    }
    private ListNode helper(ListNode head) {
        // base case
        if (head.next == null)  {  
            last = head;
            return head;
        }
        // general case
        ListNode prev = reverseList(head.next);  // should be ListNode prev = helper(head.next);
        prev.next = head;
        head.next = null;
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a tag for the programming language you use.

Comment: Using a "global" (last) in a recusive function is usually a bad sign.

Comment: Another bad sign is the fact that you return something from the method `helper` which is not used in `reverseList`...

Comment: Thank you all guys! I am so careless, write wrong method name. But why it is not good to use global variable in recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work, because in the first pass of the `helper` method

```
ListNode prev = reverseList(head.next);
```

returns [3, 2], and then you assign your old `head` (1) to be the next node after the new head of the reversed list (3). Therefore, the end result is [3, 1].

Comment: Thank you so much, I know I have made an error due to my carelessness. I pay more attention to the logical but pay less attention to my writing.